# Strassen algorithm - is it possible to do pxq matrix multiplication?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, strassen

I am trying to find a pxq matrix multiplication implementation in c using the Strassen algorithm. I am not sure it is possible.

In wikipedia the algorithm is written like this:

```
M1 = (A + D) * (E + H) = AE + AH + DE + DH
M2 = (A + B) * H = AH + BH
```

but that will not work for a pxq matrix. This approach is defined for 2x2 matrix, not a pxq matrix. For that a loop of some kind is necessary, but I am not sure what kind? It may not be possible?

**UPDATE:**

WHY I AM ASKING THIS ?

I am pretty sure that the Strassen algorithm is a super fast one (no personal experaince. just reviews) even I have to write some code for large matrix multiplications (contains number of rows and columns), and then number of rows and columns which will keep changing every time. So, I need to write one for pxq matrix.  So, I want to confirm whether it is possible...

Strassen_algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Comment: @Henrik bro i think you didn't get me :/

Comment: What are the sizes of your two matrices?

Comment: To elaborate: you can partition your matrices into square matrices of appropriate size and use Strassen's algorithm to multiply those.

Comment: @Bathsheba here lies the problem! it depends.. some times it will be 8x8 and some times 18x18 and not square some times..

Comment: Oh is *that* all? These days Strassen is *worse* than the simple algebraic way for matrices of rank less than about 1,000. It also suffers from numerical instability. You are best off using a highly optimised 3rd party library.

Comment: about 1000 :O i guess mine will always be less than that :D thanks mate.. worse ? well! any suggestions to me..

Comment: also refer to `LAPACK`. This is a package for common linear algebra operations. The codes are highly optimized

Comment: theoretically, you get the same order of magnitude performance if you pad the matrix with 0s in order to get a square matrix. (except for the fact that you have to pad the 0s?)